# Help with induction question

Tags: induction

I'm trying to prove the following equation by induction, but my base case isn't working. [image]

for all n>2.

For my base case I did n=3, and on the LHS I got 8/9 and the RHS I got 2/3.

Helppp.

Comment: You miscalculated. $(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{3^2}) = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{8}{9} = \frac{24}{36} = \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Base case gives 2/3 LHS *and* RHS

Comment: For $n=3$ your lhs is $(1-\frac 14)(1-\frac 19)=\frac 34\,\frac 89=\frac 23$.

Comment: OHHHH. I get it now. I was just plugging 3 in for (1-1/n^2) not also using what comes before it.

Comment: And then quick question. To prove using induction, would I multiply (n+1) to both sides of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left hand side is

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{8}{9} = \frac23$$

and so is the right hand side:

$$\frac{3 + 1}{2\cdot 3} = \frac46=\frac23$$

Comment: And then quick question. To prove using induction, would I multiply (n+1) to both sides of the equation or add (n+1)?

Comment: @ematth7 You would change all values of $n$ to $n+1$. So, on the left, you would get one more factor in the multiplication, and on the right, you would get $$\frac{(n+1) + 1}{2\cdot (n+1)}$$